# unable to redirect after login in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

hello guys i am new to reactjs as i was trying to authenticate user with node js backend although i am able to print the json msg in console but unable to redirect it to homepage. Can somebody help.. here is the code of login.js(client side react)...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Login.css';
import {Link, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {history} from 'history';

class AddLogin extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            user_email : "",
            user_password: "",
            user_remember : ""
        }   

    }
    change = e => 
    {
     this.setState({
         [e.target.name] : e.target.value
     })
    }
    getWebsite = () => {
        fetch("/").then(console.log(this.state));
    };
    onSubmit = e =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log(this.state);
        this.setState({
            user_email : "",
        user_password: "",
        user_remember : ""
        })


        fetch('login', {
            method : "POST",
            headers : {
              "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            body : JSON.stringify(this.state)

          })
          .then(function(response){return response.json();})
          .then(function(json){
               if(json.success===true){
                console.log(json);
                // this.props.onRouteChange('/');
                this.props.history.push("/")
          }
        else{
            console.log("data 404");


        }})
          .then(this.getWebsite)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <body class="my-login-page">
    <section class="h-100">
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center h-100">
                <div class="card-wrapper">
                    <div class="brand">
                        <img src="img/logo.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="card fat">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Login</h4>
                            <form method="POST">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">E-Mail Address</label>

                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="user_email" value={this.state.user_email} onChange={e => this.change(e)} required autofocus />
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password">Password
                                        <a href="forgot.html" class="float-right">
                                            Forgot Password?
                                        </a>
                                    </label>
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="user_password" value={this.state.user_password} onChange={e => this.change(e)} required data-eye />
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="user_remember" value={this.state.user_remember} onchange={e => this.change(e)}/> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group no-margin">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick = {e => this.onSubmit(e)} >
                                        Login
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="margin-top20 text-center">
                                    Don't have an account? <Link to ="/Register">Create One</Link>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </body>


            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddLogin;
```

here is the backend code (node.js code....)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var con = require('./db');
var func = require('./func.js');
var edo=require('./edonomix.js');

// router.get('/',function(req, res, next) 
// {

//   if(req.session.adminid)
//   {   
//     res.json({"success":true,'msg':'admin home page'});
//   }
//   else
//   {     
//     res.json({"success":true,'msg':'admin login page'});
//   }      
// });

router.post('/',function(req,res)
{

  if(req.session.adminid)
  {
    //data at home page   
    res.json({"success":true,'msg':'admin home page'});
  }
  else
  {   
        req.check('user_password','invalid password at least 6 character required').isLength({min:6,max:100});
        req.check('user_email','invalid username').isLength({min:2,max:100}).isEmail();

        var verrs=req.validationErrors();
        if(verrs)
        {
          res.json({ success:false,msg: verrs[0].msg,});
        }   
        else
        {
              console.log(req.ip);
              var admin = 
              {
                email:req.body.user_email,
                password:req.body.user_password
              };
              con.query("select *  from admin where email_id=?",admin.email,function(err,result,fields)
              {
                  if(err)
                  {
                          console.log(err);
                          res.json({'success':false});
                  }
                  else if(result.length==1)
                  {
                      if(edo.hashPassword(admin.password)===result[0].password)
                      {

                        var hour = 3600000; 
                        req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + hour);
                        req.session.cookie.maxAge = hour;
                        req.session.adminid=result[0].admin_id;
                        res.json({'success':true,'msg':'admin home page'})
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        //wrong pass
                        res.json({"success":true,'msg':'admin login page invalid email/password'});
                      }     
                  }
                  else
                  { 
                      res.json({"success":true,'msg':'admin login page wrong email'});    
                  }      
              });

        }

  }        
});

module.exports = router;
```

and here is the App.js code(react code here)...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
import AddProduct from './components/Product/AddProduct';
import ProductTable from './components/Product/ProductTable';
import AddBlog from './components/Blog/AddBlog';
import AddUser from './components/User/AddUser';
import AddPartner from './components/Partner/AddPartner';
import AddForms from './components/Forms/AddForms';
import Signin from './components/Login/AddLogin';
import Register from './components/Login/Register';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import AddEquipment from './components/Equipment/AddEquipment';
import ViewEquipment from './components/Equipment/ViewEquipment';
import AddCustomer from './components/Customer/AddCustomer';
import CustomerTable from './components/Customer/CustomerTable';  
import Admin from './components/Admin/Admin';
import AMC from './components/AMC/AMC';
import Complaint from './components/Complaint/Complaint';
import Employee from './components/Employee/Employee';
import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile';
import Schedule from './components/Schedule/Schedule';
import Site from './components/Site/Site';
import Zone from './components/Zone/Zone';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      route: 'signin',
      isSignedIn: false,
    }
  }

  onRouteChange = (route) => {
    if (route === 'signout') {
      this.setState({isSignedIn: false})
    } else if (route === '/') {
      this.setState({isSignedIn: true})
      console.log(this.state.route);
    }
    else{
      console.log('thi is else');
    }
    this.setState({route: route});
  }




  render() {
   const { isSignedIn, route } = this.state;

    return (

        <div>

        <Navigation isSignedIn={isSignedIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        { route === '/'
        ?
        <div>
        <Header />
        <Sidebar />
        <Route path = "/" exact component = {Home} />
        <Route path = "/AddProduct" exact = {true} component = {AddProduct} />
        <Route path = "/ProductTable" exact = {true} component = {ProductTable} />
        <Route path="/AddBlog" exact = {true} component = {AddBlog} />
        <Route path = "/AddUser" exact = {true} component = {AddUser} />
        <Route path = "/AddPartner" exact = {true} component = {AddPartner} />  
        <Route path = "/AddForms" exact = {true} component = {AddForms} />
        <Route path = "/Register" exact = {true} component = {Register} />
        <Route path = "/AddEquipment" exact component = {AddEquipment} />
        <Route path = "/ViewEquipment" exact component = {ViewEquipment} />
        <Route path = "/AddCustomer" exact component = {AddCustomer} />
        <Route path = "/CustomerTable" exact component = {CustomerTable} /> 
        <Route path = "/Admin" exact = {true} component = {Admin} />
        <Route path = "/AMC" exact = {true} component = {AMC} />
        <Route path = "/Complaint" exact = {true} component = {Complaint} />
        <Route path = "/Employee" exact = {true} component = {Employee} />
        <Route path = "/Profile" exact = {true} component = {Profile} />
        <Route path = "/Schedule" exact = {true} component = {Schedule} />
        <Route path = "/Site" exact = {true} component = {Site} />
        <Route path = "/Zone" exact = {true} component = {Zone} />
        </div>
        : (
             route === 'signin'
             ? <Signin loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
             : <Register loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
            )
        }

        <Footer />

          </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you might not be tracking state? My advice would be to get `redux` involved. [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) is an easy way of keeping track of state without hitting your back end every time you need data. It's a little tricky to wrap your head around at first, but once you've got it down, you'll never go back.

Redux will allow you to keep track of your jwt or whatever you're using to validate your authentication on the front end.